# if statement for DateTime calculations based on List of Integers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have variable `aTime` with type `DateTime` ex. `2021-02-23 11:51:42.190045`

I have a list of integers `someNumbers` ex. `[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`

I'm now trying to write an if statement to do a calculation such that:

*If today's date (only the day in `DateTime.now()`, not the exact time to the second) equals `aTime` plus one of the integers in `someNumbers`, then return...*

How do I write that logic in this map?

```
Container(
          child: Column(
            children: theReviewItems.map(
              (e) {
                if (DateTime.now() == e.date.add(Duration(days: SOME LIST OF NUMBERS)))
                  return ReviewBuilder(
                    entryTitle: e.title,
                    entryAuthor: e.author,
                    entryDate: e.date,
                    entryNotes: e.notes,
                    entryRelatedUrl: e.relatedUrl,
                  );
                  else return Container();
              },
            ).toList(),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
   someNumbers.map((el) => e.date.add(Duration(days: el))).contains(DateTime.now().day)
```

Comment: Well, it took me four hours, but your answer helped me come up with this monstrosity:
`if (e.frequencyInDays.map((x) => DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(e.date.add(Duration(days: x)))).toList().contains(DateFormat.yMMMMd().format(DateTime.now())))`